# PyQt5: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python

I try to start learning PyQt5 in blender but i've got this error when i try to import a module.

```
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found
```

This is my import line:

```
import sys

sys.path.append('C:\\Users\\pistiwique\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python35\\Lib\\site-packages')

from PyQt5 import QtGui
```

If i test these lines whith PyCharm, there is no probleme so it seems to come from Blender but why ?

Comment: There must be a problem with your GPU. Try changing/updating your drivers. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I remember that i ran into this error too. I think the problem was the qwindow.dll.

For me the necessary steps were: install the correct PyQt5 version directly into the python directory of the binary. For 2.76 the PyQt folder has to be in the 2.76\python\lib\site-packages directory.Then you need to grab the qwindow.dll, put it into a folder called platforms, and put it asides the Blender exe. And you should be ready to go.